# Validation by jquery, not change background

Tags: jquery

I have code that verify if checked (selected) item from id="Zelenina" (it is *select* with *option* item) or item type=file. When I choose at least one of them, backgrounds do green. It is ok. After I back choose empty item (is it one of possibility at select, this item has got empty *value*), backgrounds are green steadily. It is wrong. I want to initial backgrounds (*background: #ccc;*) Can I ask about any idea?

I need change backgrouds back when item is empty one of them.

Thanks.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#obsah_pole').bind("click",function() {    
     if($('#Zelenina').val() != '' || $('#myFile').val() != ''){
      $('#zelenina').css('background-color', 'green');
      $('#myFile').css('background-color', 'green');
     // alert('Vybrano');
       return false; }
        else {
       //   alert('Nevybrano');
          $('#zelenina').css('background-color', 'red');
           $('#myFile').css('background-color', 'red');            
              } 
          }); 
    });
```

Comment: IDs are case-sensitive. Make sure the `#Zelenina`s match.

Comment: Or `#zelenina` will match. You are mixing case. (Z in the if z in css)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Class and ID attributes are case sensitive, so it looks like you need to change one of those Zs to lower-case:

```
if($('#Zelenina').val() != '' || $('#myFile').val() != ''){
```

should be:

```
if($('#zelenina').val() != '' || $('#myFile').val() != ''){
```

See http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/casesensitivity

Answer (score 0):

yes, it is truth. I have  bind by  that has got background. My code is

```
    <span id="zelenina" style="background-color: #0c0c0c; padding: 10px; margin: 5px;"> <select id="zelenina" name="Zelenina"> 
<option value="">--</option> 
<option value="Mrkev">Mrkev</option> 
<option value="Okurka">Okurka</option> 
<option value="Rajce">Rajce</option> 
</select> 
</span>
```